# Spring Boot @Async method *sometimes* not invoked

Tags: spring, spring-boot

My Spring Boot application provides the following REST controller which invokes two methods of a `Service`. One of these methods is annotated with `@Async` so it should run asynchronously.

The main application class is annotated with `@EnableAsync`.

The problem I observed is: Basically, the async method is executed. I can see the corresponding log entries in the production system. But it seems as if *sometimes* the async method does not get invoked. There are file ids in the database which do not appear in the logs.

Do you have any idea when this behavior could occur?

**REST controller**

```java
@PostMapping(consumes = MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<Void> uploadDocument(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile multipartFile) {    
    long fileId = fileService.save(multipartFile);
    file.generateThumbnail(fileId);
    return ResponseEntity.ok().build();
}
```

**FileService**

```java
@Transactional
public long save(MultipartFile multipartFile) {
    // saves the file...
    return fileId;
}

@Async
@Transactional
public void generateThumbnail(long fileId) {
    // generate thumbnail
    log.info("Starting thumbnail generation for fileId {}", fileId);
    file.setThumbnailId(thumbnailId);
}
```

Comment: How do you obtain `file` in `generateThumbnail`?

Answer (score 0):

Calling a async method from FileService does not work as async. You must create another Service for async method and call it from your service.

Reason:

> self-invocation – calling the async method from within the same class
> – won't work the method needs to be public so that it can be proxied.
> And self-invocation doesn't work because it bypasses the proxy and
> calls the underlying method directly.

Resources: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-async

Comment: `generateThumbnail` is not called from the same class.

Comment: As @SarvarNishonboyev mentioned, the `generateThumbnail` method is called from the controller class. Thus, it's not called from the same service.